# Export layer to PostgreSQL and name with space

Tags: qgis, postgresql

I have a layer in QGIS called "Limite administrative". I have connected a PostgreSQL database.
I use "Export layer to PostgreSQL" and the export works.

My problem is that the name of the layer is transformed to "Limiteadministrative" (the space is dropped down).

Is it a way to forced the table/column names to put the string in double quotes? As it is the case in some other apps?

Comment: Have you tried enclosing the table name in double quotes, table to export to = "your name"?

Comment: No, it doesn't work... What is strange, is if I take the layer and drop it directly in the postgreSQL database in the browser, the name of the table keeps the space. But not if I use the process "Export to PostgreSQL".

Comment: If everything else fails, you can try renaming the table in Postgres

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that by disabling laundering from the tool "GDAL-Vector miscellaneous-Export to PostgreSQL" the space in the name would be preserved. I do not understand why you would like to keep the space but that is not my headache.

[image]

If that does not work then you can use ogr2ogr for making the export.

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=mydb user=user password=pw" -lco launder=no -nln "A Layer NamE wiTH headACHE" test.json
```

Test the result:

```
ogrinfo PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=mydb user=user password=pw"
...
88: A Layer NamE wiTH headACHE (Polygon)
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work! It preserve the space in the attribute table, but not in the name of the layer.

Comment: "I do not understand why you would like to keep the space but that is not my headache". Because I have symbology that use the name of the layers, and I don't want to redo it...

Comment: Mmmh, it seems to work, BUT the name is not anymore in Uppercase (first letter).

Comment: I edited my answer and added an ogr2ogr command that keeps all the oddities that you can wish.